# Best approach to store and retrieve files?

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, ftp, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm developing an application using **C# 4.0** and **SQL Server 2008 R2 Express**, my application needs to store and retrieve files (docx, pdf, png) locally and remotely, which approach would be the best?

1. Store the files in **separate database** (problem: restricted to 10 GB)
2. Use a **windows shared folder** (who to do?)
3. Use an **FTP server** (which server and library and how to do?)

Comment: Object storage like S3 is the current trend. You can also setup a shared filesystem, although managing it is quite a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server supports [`FILESTREAM`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), so if you have enough control over the SQL Server install to enable that feature then it seems like a good fit for you.

> FILESTREAM integrates the SQL Server Database Engine with an NTFS file system by storing varbinary(max) binary large object (BLOB) data as files on the file system. Transact-SQL statements can insert, update, query, search, and back up FILESTREAM data. Win32 file system interfaces provide streaming access to the data.

Files stored directly in the file system with `FILESTREAM` don't count towards the database size because they aren't stored in the DB.

To confirm with an official source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-compatibility-with-other-sql-server-features

> SQL Server Express supports FILESTREAM. The 10-GB database size limit does not include the FILESTREAM data container.

Comment: Does FILESTREAM allow more than 10 GB?

Comment: See the last sentence of my answer "Files stored directly in the file system with FILESTREAM don't count towards the database size because they aren't stored in the DB.", so they don't count towards the 10gb limit.